# 301 redirect url with query string not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have http://www.example.com/search/default.htm?Search=rhian need to redirect to http://www.example.com/index.php/sitemap/?search_paths[]=&query=rhian

And there are multiple url like this to redirect. I have tried different methods but it doesn't seems to work.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/search/default\.htm$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Search=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://example.com/sitemap/?search_paths[]=&query=%1.pdf [R=301,L]
```

I have edited my question with the method I have tried.

Comment: Please provide what have you tried too!

Comment: What exactly happens when you go to the old url?

Comment: @starkeen it goes to 404 page

Comment: I think your Rewrite destination is wrong, it should be **http://example.com/index.php/sitemap/** .

Comment: @starkeen no, if I give Redirect 301/search/default.htm https://www.example.com/sitemap it will go to sitemap with the search string. But that is not I wanted.

Comment: Can you post your complete .htaccess in the question?

Comment: What Apache version do you have?